# A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:checkDebugManifest' (type 'CheckManifest') in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I was building my app, when this error occured while building -

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:checkDebugManifest' (type 'CheckManifest').
  - Type 'CheckManifest' property 'manifest' has @Input annotation used on property of type 'File'.

    Reason: A property of type 'File' annotated with @Input cannot determine how to interpret the file.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Annotate with @InputFile for regular files.
      2. Annotate with @InputDirectory for directories.
      3. If you want to track the path, return File.absolutePath as a String and keep @Input.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/validation_problems.html#incorrect_use_of_input_annotation for more details about this problem.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 0s
```

I have no idea why this error occured, while everything was working fine just before. Please someone help me with this.

Comment: I have the same problem since 3 days ago, and I yet can't resolved it.

Comment: @juliosegura Well I just downgraded the grafle version to 5.4.6 and it worked. Though i would like to know, how can we remove this error if we want to use gradle version 7

Comment: @Shrenyansh you right, I downgraded the gradle version to 5.6.4 and that resolved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @juliosegura no problem bruh. If you liked my question and answer, please do consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 53):

In my case I got such error after upgrading Gradle to version 7.

I fixed it by updating a version 'com.android.tools.build:gradle' in project build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much! It also worked for me!

Answer (score 12):

I have upgrade the android studio to 4.X.X that time android studio automatically upgraded all my gradle files.

You need to check two files

1. gradle-wrapper.properties
2. project build.gradle file

In gradle-wrapper.properties need to use

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
```

and in project build.gradle file

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2
```

Answer (score 9):

This error occurs due to the upgraded version of Gradle (Gradle 7+). You can resolve this issue in two ways.

1. Upgrade the `compileSdkVersion` to 31 in app `build.gradle` file,

   ```
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 31
       ...
   }
   ```

   Update **gradle build tools** version to **4.2+** in project `build.gradle` file

   ```
   buildscript {
      ...
      dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
      }
   }
   ```

**or**

2. Downgrade the gradle version to 6.x instead of 7.x

Update **gradle distribution version** to 6.5 in `gradle-wrapper.properties` file

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
```

Update **gradle build tools** version to **4.2+** in project `build.gradle` file

```
buildscript {
   ...
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without downgrading Gradle version (currently `7.0.2`), **upgrading dependencies** gave clearer errors indicating issues with `compileSdkVersion`.

So I **set it to `31` (suggested version)**, and it completely resolved all the problems.

**Tip:** Some other problems with `kotlin-version` and `firebase` versions came up after, but errors were clear and everything could be fixed just following the details.

Answer (score 0):

Minimum supported Gradle version is **6.7.1**. Current version is **6.5**. If using the gradle wrapper

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by updating compileSdkVersion 33 in build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

When working with gradle version 3.4.2, I was able to solve it by changing the jvm args  in gradle.properties file to:

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if there are errors in `build.gradle` file in both project and app levels. clean errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me.

1. Check if your project is running on AndroidX if not. Migrate your project to AndroidX.

> Refoctor -> Migrate to AndroidX

---

2. Update all your dependencies

---

3. Ensure that your compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion are at least 33

> android {
> compileSdkVersion 33
> defaultConfig {
> targetSdkVersion 33
> }
> }

---

4. Add the following code in your gradle.properties

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED